# How to use Redisson to upload byte array in Redis Cluster?

Tags: java, caching, redis, client, redisson

I haven't found an explanation about how to upload pure array of bytes. Redisson has a RBitSet but it manages an array of bits not bytes. How to store a byte array by using Redisson?

Here is my configuration:

```
Config config = new Config();

LoadBalancer loadBalancer = new RoundRobinLoadBalancer();

config.useClusterServers()
        .setScanInterval(5000) // cluster state scan interval in milliseconds
        .addNodeAddress("192.168.0.14:6379", "192.168.0.15:6379")
        .setReadMode(ReadMode.MASTER_SLAVE)
        .setLoadBalancer(loadBalancer)
        .setPassword("bTFBx1NYYWRMTUEyNHhsCg")
        .setSlaveConnectionPoolSize(10)
        .setMasterConnectionPoolSize(10);

RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was helped on github. Here is how to write a byte array:

```
RBucket<byte[]> bucket = redisson.getBucket("myBucket", ByteArrayCodec.INSTANCE);
byte[] myarray = ...
bucket.set(myarray);
```

Comment: So we need to have the key as a String? What if we have the key as a byte array too?
redisson.getBucket(byte[] key, codec)??

Lettuce has a method for it

Answer (score 3):

Since 2.6.0 / 3.1.0 version Redisson provides `RBinaryStream` object. It exposes `OutputStream` object for more convient usage:

```
byte[] content = ...

RBinaryStream stream = redisson.getBinaryStream("anyStream");

stream.set(content);
// or
OutputStream os = stream.getOuputStream();
os.write(content);
```

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between this alternative and an RBucket with ByteArrayCodec?